# Save Semantic data in GraphDB triplestore using Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, processor, graphdb

I want to save the big semantic data (turtle format), which is transformed via a NiFi processor, in GraphDB. I am using InvokeHTTP in NiFi, but I am not succeeding. I have always Connection timed out (Connection timed out) to the remote URL. Any help ? or other suggestion to another nifi processor to use for GRaphDB ?

InvokeHTTP processor with the configuration in Content-type : text/turtle, Any help ? or other suggestion to another nifi processor to use for GRaphDB ?

Comment: `Connection timed out` is a network problem between your nifi server and target hostname. Remote connect to a server where nifi is running and troubleshoot connection.